# UPDATE a table with Multiple values that are based on a queries output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

To validate that the `EMPID` is in both the `[TEMPTABLE]` AND `[FMN0]`.  I use this code:

```
Select T.empid 
from dbo.TEMPTABLE as T 
JOIN dbo.FMN0 as N0 on T.EMPID = N0.EMPID
```

To validate that `RMID` and `BLDGCODE` are both in the `[TEMPTABLE]` and `[FMA0]`.  I use this code:

```
SELECT
  rmid
FROM dbo.FMA0 AS A0
WHERE T.rmid = A0.rmid;

SELECT
  bldgcode
FROM dbo.FMA0 AS A0
WHERE T.bldgcode = A0.bldgcode;
```

**NOTE**

I am attempting to `UPDATE` the `[TESTTABLE]` with the `EMPID` that corresponds to the correct `RMID` AND `BLDGCODE` combination.

And if the combination is wrong or non existent, then print out the incorrect `RMID, BLDGCODE, EMPID` values `FROM [TEMPTABLE]`.

Keep in mind there could be, for example, a `(BLDGCODE)` and a `(RMID)` of 200 assigned to multiple Employees `(EMPID)`.

**This code is not working:**

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE
SET EMPID = (SELECT T.empid
             FROM dbo.TEMPTABLE AS T
             JOIN dbo.FMN0 AS N0 ON T.EMPID = N0.EMPID)
FROM dbo.FMN0
WHERE SPACEID IN (SELECT auto_key
                  FROM dbo.FMA0 AS A0
                  JOIN dbo.TEMPTABLE AS T
                  ON T.RMID = A0.RMID
                  AND T.BLDGCODE = A0.BLDGCODE)
```

An error is given saying multiple values are being returned?

Is there another way to accomplish this?  If Else statements maybe?

---

**Table's Structure:**

**[TEMPTABLE]**

```
BLDGCODE    RMID       EMPID
HCTR        918        User3
HCTR        920        User5
HCTR        912/914    User1
HCTR        912/914    User6
HCTR        100001     User2
HCTR        916        User47
```

**[FMN0]**

```
EMPID
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
User6
User7
```

**[FMA0]**

```
auto_key    BLDGCODE    RMID
AX123       HCTR        910
AX124       HCTR        911
AX125       HCTR        912/914
AX128       HCTR        915
AX129       HCTR        916
AX131       HCTR        917
AX132       HCTR        918
AX133       HCTR        919
AX134       HCTR        920
```

**[TESTTABLE]**(Current state)

```
SPACEID     EMPID   
AX132       NULL
AX125       NULL
AX125       NULL
AX134       NULL
AX129       NULL
```

**[TESTTABLE]**(Desired Result)

```
SPACEID     EMPID   
AX132       User3
AX125       User1
AX125       User6
AX134       User5
AX129       NULL
```

> Output:"This information is incorrect"
>   (minus the asterisk)

```
BLDGCODE    RMID       EMPID
HCTR        *100001*   User2
HCTR        916        *User47*
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without more detail on the table structures, but if you as AND T.rmdi = A0.rmid AND T.bldgcode = A0.bldgcode to the first subquery does that give you what you want? Doing that may allow you to drop the second subquery altogether

Comment: Thre is not T in this. SELECT rmid FROM dbo.FMA0 AS A0 WHERE T.rmid = A0.rmid;

Comment: What is TESTTABLE?  What table has auto_key.  Show some effort.   This one of the most convoluted questions I have seen and it has up votes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the Replies, suggestions and edits.  **I will edit the original post with the table structures and desired outcome**.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> I am attempting to UPDATE the [TESTTABLE] with the EMPID that corresponds to the correct RMID AND BLDGCODE combination.

You could join in your where clause, do the conditional where TESTTABLE's EMPID doesn't match AO's EMPID as follows:

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE
SET EMPID = T.EMPID
FROM dbo.FMN0 AS AO
    INNER JOIN dbo.TEMPTABLE AS T
        ON T.RMID = A0.RMID AND T.BLDGCODE = A0.BLDGCODE
WHERE TESTTABLE.EMPID <> T.EMPID
AND TESTTABLE.SPACEID = auto_key --not sure if this comes from TEMPTABLE or FMN0
```

**Edit:**

I don't understand how you could have TESTTABLE knowing the auto_key / SPACEID before running this query.  Since there could multiple EMPIDs associated with a SPACEID, this is why you are getting the error and there really isn't a way to associate *which* SPACEID goes with *which* EMPID (and is why you are getting the error in question) without some logic that says "get the first, or the second, or the third".  It's a procedural / sequential way to attack an inherently set-based problem.

Assuming you are wanting to validate what is in TEMPTABLE and put in an *empty* TESTTABLE and get invalid entries in TEMPTABLE, you could do the following:

```
SELECT 
    temp.*,
    SPACEID = CASE 
        WHEN N0.EMPID IS NOT NULL AND A0.auto_key IS NULL THEN A0.auto_key 
        ELSE NULL 
    END,
    ErrorMessage = CASE 
        WHEN N0.EMPID IS NULL THEN 'EMPID doesn''t exist' 
        WHEN A0.auto_key IS NULL THEN 'Room / code combination doesn''t exist' 
        ELSE NULL
    END
INTO #errorCheck
FROM TEMPTABLE temp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FMN0 AS N0 
        ON N0.EMPID = temp.EMPID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FMA0 AS A0 
        ON A0.BLDGCODE = temp.BLDGCODE AND A0.RMID = temp.RMID;

INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (
    SPACEID,
    EMPID
)
SELECT 
    SPACEID,
    EMPID
FROM #errorCheck
WHERE SPACEID IS NOT NULL; -- entries that have valid EMPID, BLDGCODE & RMID

SELECT
    BLDGCODE,
    RMID,
    EMPID,
    ErrorMessage
FROM #errorCheck
WHERE SPACEID IS NULL; --Entries for Output:"This information is incorrect"
```

If you are insistent on matching to the existing entries in TESTTABLE from the above, you could change the above with subqueries / window functions to get the first, second, third, etc EMPID associated with the given SPACEID.  However, if that is true, I still would like to know how TESTTABLE is *initially* populated and if the query above couldn't be run at that time instead of trying to match TESTTABLE & TEMPTABLE after the fact.

Comment: FMN0(N0) is a different table then FMA0(A0).  In the code above FMN0 is using an alias of A0.

Comment: I will try this code and let you know the outcome.  It may need to be slightly tweaked.

Comment: The TESTTABLE will be initially populated using the code below:

Comment: 'INSERT into TESTTABLE (SPACEID, BLDGRMID)  SELECT auto_key, BLDGRMID FROM dbo.FMA0 as A0  JOIN TEMPTABLE as T on T.RMID = A0.RMID and T.BLDGCODE = A0.BLDGCODE;'

Comment: What is ultimately trying to be accomplished with TESTTABLE / TEMPTABLE?  It seems you're trying to match them at different times that may be unnecessary since it seems you are only wanting to validate the data from TEMPTABLE.

Comment: Yes i need to validate the data from TEMPTABLE before Assigning that data to the TESTTABLE.  My current approach has been to divide the process into two steps.  First INSERTing the SpaceID and BLDGRMID(An automated concantenation of Bldgcode and RMID from [FMA0], in case you were wondering).   Second, UPDATE the TESTTABLE so that the EMPID corresponds to the correct SpaceID.  The validation is needed as an error checking control, to prevent incorrect TEMPTABLE data from being entered into the TESTTABLE.

Comment: You are correct that, besides writing the code to successfully execute this task, the dilemma has been matching seperate EMPID's with a SpaceID that is the same in two rows.

Comment: I guess based on the above I'm not sure why you wouldn't use the approach I outlined and not split into two steps - this way, the information in TEMPTABLE is validated correctly (check that EMPID exists in FMN0 and that RMID / BLDGCODE exists in FMA0).  You're creating too much complexity by splitting into two steps a set-based operation that should be done in one step.  Hope this helps.